# how to get data using Http.get from my project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-http

I got a ts file that contain some users:

quickstart-muster/app/mock/user.mock.ts:

```
import {User} from "../user";

export const USERS:User[]=[
  new User(....);
];
```

A serice - quickstart-muster/app/services/user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {User} from "../user";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:Http){}

  public loadUsers():Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get('../mock/user.mock.ts')
      .map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

I know thats not gonna work and its not, i get 404 error that say he can't find .../mock/user.mock.ts.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Try two dots instead of three: "../mock/user.mock.ts". Please add a tag for the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load a JSON file instead like it would come from the API:

**/data.json**

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "...",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

and then you can load it like this:

```ts
public loadUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
  return this.http.get('data.json')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

---

You could also create an `Observable` from scratch like this:

```ts
public loadUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        observer.onNext(USERS);
        observer.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thansk for the answer! Is there anyway I could use "new User(params...)" inside a json file? If not, is that the only way to acomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I added another possibility! :)

Comment: You can put whatever value you want in the `.onNext` call. Potentially an array with users!

Comment: Okay I changed to : http.get('.../mock/user.mock.json') but I still get 404 not found error. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, I dont know where `...` should lead, as I only know `..`, but you have to enter a relative address from a browser's view point anyway.

Comment: If i'm not allowed to use "..", how do I tell the browser where my file is?

Comment: I'm only intersted with a solution that use http.get(..). Thanks for all the help anyways

Comment: Haha, ok ... then just put that JSON file besides your `index.html` and the browser will find it at `'data.json'` ... Your start point of 'relativity' is the folder with the `index.html`. If you have a folder called app and then mock, then the right path might be `'app/mock/data.json'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.resolve instead of http get

```
public loadUsers():Observable<User[]>{
    return Promise.resolve([ new User(....);]);
  }
```

Comment: I want to use http.get and later I will only change the adress to a real server.